# How to fetch a dummy record if a sub-query count is zero?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to fetch one dummy record from `tableA` when the count of records in `tableA` is zero. If the table count is more than zero,then there should not be the dummy value X fetched.

It is something like:

```
Select  'X' As Count from tableA
When
(Select count (*) From tableA) >0
```

Comment: When asking questions, please try to keep titles as succinct and useful as possible - there's no need to add `Please help on ...` as this is redundant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) 
                           FROM tableA > 0
                           THEN SELECT 'X' AS Count 
                                FROM tableA
                           ELSE SELECT field1, field2, field3 etc
                                FROM TableA
               END)
```

Comment: Its not working.Can select statement be used inside Case ?